# Creating a thread with a Mockito mocked Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class that implements `Runnable` called `DoThingInALoop`. It is given to a second class that will create a thread out of it, call this thread `Boss`. The `Boss` can tell the runnable to quit and let the thread terminate. Later, it can create a new thread with that same `DoThingInALoop`.

When I am writing unit tests for the `Boss` I want to mock the `DoThingInALoop` because it is not the object under test. However, `DoThingInALoop` extends a class `Loop` and the code for `Loop` is actually being executed in the thread spawned by the `Boss`. That code of course runs into `NullPointerException`s because none of the member variables are set, because the object is mocked.

How can I prevent Java's `Thread` from "seeing through" the mock?

```
public class Loop implements Runnable {
    private final Object member = new Object();
    public final void run() {
        // This code runs, but it shouldn't
        synchronized (member) { // Throws NPE
            ...
        }
        // Hook for subclasses
        try {
            subclassRun();
        } finally {
            // Mandatory cleanup (unrelated to question)
        }
}

public class DoThingInALoop extends Loop {
    public void subclassRun() { ... }
    public void stopDoingThingsInALoop() {
        // Set instance member that on next loop iteration signals thread to return
    }
}

public class Boss {
    private final DoThingsInALoop toBeMocked;
    public Boss(final DoThingsInALoop toBeMocked) {
        this.toBeMocked = toBeMocked;
    }
    public void start() {
        // Simplified
        new Thread(toBeMocked).start();
    }
    public void stop() {
        toBeMocked.stopDoingThingsInALoop();
    }
}


public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        // Setup Mocks
        DoThingsInALoop mockLoop = mock(DoThingsInALoop.class);
        Boss boss = new Boss(mockLoop);

        // Run test
        boss.start();

        // After the above line runs, a new thread is started and
        // the run() method of `Loop` executes until the NPE
        // is hit when it attempts to access a member variable
        // which is of course not set because it is a mocked object

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post something reproducible. `Loop#run` won't be called. Some fake `DoThingInALoopProxyClass#run` will be called that won't do anything.

Comment: Unless your `run` method is actually `final`...

Comment: Have you tried by stubbing the `run()` method in your mock? `doNothing().when(mockLoop).run();`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Apologies, I was summarizing the real code. The `Loop.run()` is final and calls another method which is a hook for `DoThingInALoop` to extend. I will update the question.

Comment: @Ruben I forgot to mention that the `Loop.run()` is final, and therefore cannot be mocked.

Comment: remove `final` from run() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is too much final for Mockito.

I would encapsulate the Thread execution in a new class that you can easily mock (let's call it `Executor`).

```
public class Executor {
    public void execute(Runnable runnable) {
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }
}
```

And then use the `Executor` in the place when you create the `Thread`.

```
public class Boss {
    private final DoThingInALoop toBeMocked;
    private final Executor executor;

    public Boss(final Executor executor, final DoThingInALoop toBeMocked) {
        this.executor = executor;
        this.toBeMocked = toBeMocked;
    }

    public void start() {
        executor.execute(toBeMocked);
    }
}
```

In your test, you just need to mock the `Executor`.

```
    DoThingInALoop mockLoop = Mockito.mock(DoThingInALoop.class);
    Executor mockExecutor = Mockito.mock(Executor.class);
    Boss boss = new Boss(mockExecutor, mockLoop);

    boss.start();

    // No NPE aynymore
    verify(mockExecutor).execute(mockLoop);
```

Another option would be to try [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/)

Comment: Seems a shame to add a level of indirection to the code solely for the purpose of unit testing, but it does effectively allow the mocking. The `Executor` could be in a second constructor, with the default constructor filling in `(runnable) -> new Thread(runnable).start()`. This way existing code could remain unchanged.